# Tinymce (chosing selector)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, tinymce

I'm trying to make gradual system with tinymce.

For example: there is a main div as "editable", when you click editable there are 4 options to add: "Slider, Google map, Content, Photo"

than, when you click "Content" it inserts "" div to, main div.

If you click "content-area" div, there should be 2 options as "one-column" "two-column". but i doesn't. It gives me again, 4 options like before. Because it defines it as a Editable div.

```
    <div class="editable">
 <div class="content-area"></div>
 </div>
```

I need to define selector as "div.editable:not(.content-area)" but i doesn't work for tinymce. How can I make it? How can I add ":not" selector to tinymce.

here is an example: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/wqeaab

Comment: Reproduce this into a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/wqeaab